# android and resources -> best implementation

Tags: android, performance

What is the best implementation:

### First:

```
class Ball extends View {
    private Animation fallAnimation;

    public void fall() {
        fallAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fall);
        startAnimation(fallAnimation);
    }

}
```

### Second:

```
class Ball extends View {
    private Animation fallAnimation;

    public void fall() {
        fallAnimation = BallLoader.loadFall();
        startAnimation(fallAnimation);
    }

}

class BallLoader {
    private static Animation fallAnimation;

    public static Animation loadFall() {
        if (fallAnimation == null) {
            fallAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.fall);
        }
        return fallAnimation;
    }

}
```

### Extend second loader:

```
class BallLoader {
    private static Animation fallAnimation;
    private static Animation moveAnimation;
    private static Animation jumpAnimation;

    public static Animation loadFall() {
        if (fallAnimation == null) {
            fallAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.fall);
        }
        return fallAnimation;
    }

    //not optimized, just for example
    public static Animation loadMove() {
        if (moveAnimation == null) {
           moveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.move);
        }
        return moveAnimation;
    }

    //not optimized, just for example
    public static Animation loadJump() {
        if (jumpAnimation == null) {
           jumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),
                R.anim.jump);
        }
        return jumpAnimation;
    }

}
```

---

### Using of this:

```
Ball ball1 = new Ball();
Ball ball2 = new Ball();
Ball ball3 = new Ball();
Ball ball4 = new Ball();
Ball ball5 = new Ball();
Ball ball6 = new Ball();
Ball ball7 = new Ball();
Ball ball8 = new Ball();
Ball ball9 = new Ball();

ball1.fall();
ball2.fall();
ball3.fall();
ball4.fall();
ball5.fall();
ball6.fall();
ball7.fall();
ball8.fall();
ball9.fall();
```

I think that first is more clear and not so confused. But will be there any problems with performance? Android loads this animations every time or maybe it's caching by android framework?...

Second is more confused and original class is very large and maybe another programmers will confused with that... I don't know, please say me what implementation is better?

Answer (score 2):

The two implementations do different things. In the first, each Ball object uses a distinct Animation object. In the second (which is a [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)), the same Animation object is shared by all Ball objects. Which is better depends on your requirements.

Comment: I this case its not singleton, its just static class. But it doesn't matter. This class is just for example. Look, when I create ball with the same animation >10 times (for example) it will load this animation >10 times? Or android cache this? and at second, third, ... times loads from cache? What variant will give us the best results? (or imagine that there is no animation loading, it's bitmap loading)

Comment: Please define "best results". What are you trying to accomplish? For the first implementation, Android will load a separate animation for each Ball instance; it does not cache it because for all it knows, you need separate instances because you plan to set separate properties after loading. (It may cache the XML somewhere, but I doubt it.) Your second implementation is exactly the Singleton pattern; see the example Java implementation in the Wikipedia article that I linked to in my answer. _"If it walks like a duck, talks like a duck, and looks like a duck, it's a duck."_

Comment: Okey... I don't think that it's singleton, because there isn't get instance method, and I don't get instance, and I don't control number of instances, actually I don't create any instances. I just called static method from this static class. Thank you for comment, may by it's really singleton and I'm wrong. If anybody else will confirm that it's really singleton, than I will change my opinion

Comment: I take it back - your second implementation isn't the singleton pattern, because it isn't legal code. (You can't return a value from a function declared `void`.) But other than that, the only difference between your code and the classic Singleton pattern is a trivial renaming of `getInstance` to `loadFall`. You control the number of instances (to one) by the logic of `loadFall`: once you've created an instance and stored it in the private `fallAnimation` variable, it will always return that instance and never create another.

Comment: may be we didn't understood each other. See first post I added "extended second class". There I showed how I imagine this class and that is why Ive disagreed that its singleton